# Well pointed endofunctors on $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

In $1$-category theory, a well pointed endofunctor of a category $C$, is an endofunctor $F:C \rightarrow C$ endowed with a natural transformation $\sigma : Id \rightarrow F$ such that the two natural transformation:

$$ \sigma F, F \sigma : F \rightrightarrows F^2 $$

are equal. As shown by [Kelly](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/unified-treatment-of-transfinite-constructions-for-free-algebras-free-monoids-colimits-associated-sheaves-and-so-on/FE2E25E4959E4D8B4DE721718E7F55EE) all kind of transfinite constructions can be conveniently formulated as iterations of well pointed endofunctors.

I would like to give the "correct" generalization of this to $\infty$-categories (where $\infty$-category means $(\infty,1)$, and more precisely quasicategories).

A natural way to do it is as follow:

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the monoidal category whose objects are non-negative integers, the monoidal structure is given by addition and there is a (unique) morphism form $m$ to $n$ if and only if $m \leqslant n$.

**Fact:** A well pointed endofunctor on a category $C$ is the same as a monoidal functor $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow End(C)$. Where $End(C)$ denotes the monoidal category of endofunctors of $C$, monoidal for composition.

This suggest the following:

**Definition:** A well pointed endofunctor on an $\infty$-category $C$ is a monoidal functor:

$$ N(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow End(C).$$

Where everything is defined following the definition of Jacob Lurie's Higher algebra, in particular $End(C)$ is the monoidal category of endofunctors of $C$ as constructed in section 4.7.1 of Higher Algebra.

This all well and nice, But I have the impression that it is possible to give a purely finitary version of this notion.

**Attempted equivalent definition :** A well pointed endofunctor on an $\infty$-category $C$ is the data of:

- An endofunctor $F:C \rightarrow C$.
- A natural transformation $\sigma: Id_C \rightarrow F$.
- An equivalence $\theta: \sigma F \sim \sigma F$ as natural transformation from $F$ to $F^2$.
- A coherence $3$-cell $\Omega$ constructed expressing the following:
  The $1$-cell $\sigma \otimes \sigma : Id \rightarrow F^2$ is naturally equivalent (without using $\theta$) to both the composite $(F \sigma) \circ \sigma$ and $(\sigma F) \circ \sigma$, hence $\theta$ "composed" with $\sigma$ induces a self equivalence of $\sigma \otimes \sigma$. One should have a $3$-cell $\Omega$ expressing that this self equivalence is the identity.

Somehow surprisingly, I havn't been able to find any other "higher coherences" that seemed to be needed, so this suggest the following question:

**Are the two definition above indeed equivalent (in an appropriate higher categorical sense) ?**

So basically that would be a "coherence theorem for well pointed endofunctor".

I convinced myself some time ago that it was indeed the case using a complicated and very combinatorial argument in a model structure. But that argument could easily have been flawed. Moreover I have the impression that there could be simpler proof of this, so I wanted to raise the question on MO to see if someone could come up with either a more elegant argument or an obvious coherence condition in higher dimension that I have missed...

Comment: Here's some evidence in favor of this rectification hypothesis. A well-pointed endofunctor $(F,\sigma,\dots)$ corresponds to an idempotent monad iff $\sigma F = F\sigma$ is an equivalence. According to HTT 5.2.7.4, this rectification hypothesis _does_ hold in the case where $\sigma F = F\sigma$ is an equivalence. I learned this from 4.17 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10425).

Comment: This is related to the fact that an idempotent in the homotopy category of an $\infty$-category, plus one additional coherence datum, can always be lifted to a homotopy coherent idempotent -- this is HTT 4.4.5.20 in the new versions -- it does not appear in the published version on HTT. Supposedly this appears as 7.3.5.14 in  older versions of HA, but it does not appear in newer versions of HA.

Comment: @TimCampion : I'm not sure I see the link. But if there is one it rather point to a negative result to my question. In the case of idempotent you can extend finite level of the coherence condition to a fully coherent idempotent but this extention is non-unique and do induce an equivalence of categories between fully coherent idempotent and "partly coherent idemponent".

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is a stable monoidal $\infty$-category then the theory of Smith ideals tells you that if you have a monoidal functor $F: \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0} \to D$ then the cofiber of the map $F(-1\to 0)$ is a monoid and every monoid arises this way.

If you take opposites this should tell you that a well pointed endofunctor must be at least as complicated as a comonad.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying exactly. Are you claiming that there is correspondence between monoidal functors $\mathbb{N} \to M$ and comonoid objects in $M$ when $M$ is stable and monoidal?

Comment: I think I have all my arrows going the right way now. Did this help? I think this says that if you have a monoidal functor $F: \mathbb{N} \to M$ the fiber of $F(0\to 1)$ is a comonoid.